# How to auto-confirm shortcut command

Tags: vimscript, functions

I have a function called Comment in my vimrc, and I have a shortcut that 'runs' this function:

```bash
nnoremap <S-Tab> :call Comment()
```

The way it currently works is I press [Shift]+[Tab] in normal mode and then at the bottom of the screen, this appears:

```bash
:call Comment()
```

Then I have to press enter again so it actually executes! Is there a way I can do this without having to press enter? Like it just automatically executes without confirmation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append `<cr>` to your mapping:

```
:nnoremap <S-Tab> :call Comment()<cr>
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you!!